# curve fitting for gas sensor(MiCs 2714)

Tags: sensor

I am trying to do gas sensor curve fitting for Mics 2714 no2. The datasheet is [here](https://www.sgxsensortech.com/content/uploads/2014/08/1107_Datasheet-MiCS-2714.pdf), and this is the graph I am trying to fit (Rs/R0 as a function of NO2 concentration):

[image]

What is the general approach to fitting an equation to a datasheet graph provided in PDF form?

Comment: maybe someone can help, but frankly, fitting which curve to what? You need to explain in more detail what kind of curve that is, and what you're trying to achieve. A plot of your curve would certainly help!

Comment: @shreyasH: Please capitalise and punctuate properly for legibility and credibility. Use proper sentences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first extract the data from the PDF graph. I extracted 8 values. You can use your eyes or some software tool.

```
0.010   0.0649
0.030   0.1914
0.087   0.5645
0.169   1.0803
0.558   3.6062
1.330   8.5681
3.346   21.9929
6.304   41.4429
```

Then fit the data using an appropriate method. I used a power fit. Again, use a tool that you are familiar with such as Scilab, Octave or MATLAB- you can even use Excel (load the optional solver) or write some code in whatever language.

Rather than a power fit, you could use a relatively high order polynomial but it might go squirrely between the points unless you have a lot of points relative to the order of the polynomial.

That gives: \$ \frac{R_X}{R_0} \approx 6.492 C^{1.007}\$ where C is the concentration of NO2 in ppm.

Finally, plot the fitted curve and compare to the pdf (left as an exercise, but this is a pretty good fit). Do not omit this step- a least-square sum of error cost function will not give good results with a very nonlinear variable since the errors at the low end will hardly contribute to the total and those at the high end will dominate (in your example, a lower order polynomial fit using a least-square fit will tend to diverge for low NO2 concentrations).

Finally, compare the results with your target accuracy and iterate if required.